# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 in adding Auth::user()->campus_id attribute Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am doing this query

```
$disposes = Disposecollect::create([
    'bag_id' => $request->input('bag_id'),
    'station_id' => $station->id,
    'undisposed_weight' => $weight->weight,
    'disposed_weight' => $weight->weight - $weight->weight,
    'status' => $request->input('status'),
    'campus_id' => Auth::user()->campus_id 
]);
```

And it suddenly it produce an error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`ecoteneo`.`disposecollects`, CONSTRAINT
>   `disposecollects_campus_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`campus_id`)
>   REFERENCES `campuses` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
>   (SQL: insert into `disposecollects` (`bag_id`, `station_id`,
>   `undisposed_weight`, `disposed_weight`, `status`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (6, 1, 5, 0, Undisposed, 2018-09-25 10:02:23,
>   2018-09-25 10:02:23))

The value of campus id from the user didn't pass in an insert query...

Is it my code in the part of:

`'campus_id' => Auth::user()->campus_id`

is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in

```
(SQL: insert into disposecollects (bag_id, station_id, undisposed_weight, disposed_weight, status, updated_at, created_at) values (6, 1, 5, 0, Undisposed, 2018-09-25 10:02:23, 2018-09-25 10:02:23))
```

There is no `campus_id` field. In Laravel, this usually means that your `campus_id` value is `null` or `empty`. I'd suggest you try to dump and die (`dd`) `Auth::user()->campus_id`so you're able to verify it's value.

`dd` means 'Dump and Die', thus meaning that Laravel will output the variable name and won't proceed to any other part of the code. If you call `dd(Auth::user())` you'll be able to see all `Auth::user()` attributes. You could also call `dd(Auth::user()->campus_id)`, but I'd suggest you trying to output the most generalized (and still useful) part of the code, as that guarantees a broader vision of the problem.

Comment: Thanks after dd I found out now that I forgot to put campus_id in $fillable in my model. Thank you!